# os.listdir(folder) function printing out the wrong order of files

Tags: python

[image]

In my folder, I have the following normal order of my files. But, when I print out the files into python using the following code:

```
for i in os.listdir(folder):
    print(i)
```

I get the following output:

```
spam2.txt
spam304.txt
spam33000.txt
spam34.txt
spam4.txt
```

Which clearly is not in the correct order, as you can see the numeric values are mixed up in the wrong way.

My question is:

> Is the function `os.listdir` making python print it this way, and is there a way to avoid this?

The output i'm trying to get is:

```
spam2.txt
spam4.txt
spam34.txt
spam304.txt
spam3044.txt
spam33000.txt
```

Please if there is any criticism to my question post it below, I'm willing to modify my question if so!

Comment: sort the `os.listdir` output. From documentation "Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation of os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory
> given by path. The **list is in arbitrary order**, and does not include
> the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the
> directory.

To get the order by numbers you can use for example regex pattern:

```
import re 
import os 

files = os.listdir('data')
re_pattern = re.compile('.+?(\d+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9+])')
files_ordered = sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(re_pattern.match(x).groups()[0]))
```

output

```py
In [1]: files
Out[1]: ['spam2.txt', 'spam3.txt', 'spam304.txt', 'spam3300.txt', 'spam34.txt']

In [2]: files_ordered
Out[2]: ['spam2.txt', 'spam3.txt', 'spam34.txt', 'spam304.txt', 'spam3300.txt']
```

Short explanation:

- The [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) accepts a `key` argument that can be used to sort your list. Here we read the number before the dot in the filename. *Note*: You have to make yourself sure that the regex pattern matches with all your files.
- `.+?` in the beginning matches anything, but is non-greedy (will match as little as possible)
- `(\d+)` will match and capture the digits, as many as there are, which you can then read from `.groups()[0]`.
- `\.` will match the dot in the filename
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` will match the file extension (alphanumeric)

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting by length like this:

```
import os
folder ="1"
for i in sorted(os.listdir(folder), key=len):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually what I was looking for exactly

Comment: Ordering by length will not make the order to be as in OP's question generally. Think about `spamegg1.txt` and `spam99.txt`.